# How does the continuous functions from this space to space $\mathbb{R}$ look like

Tags: general-topology, continuity

This particular question is from my topology quiz (now over ) and I was unable to prove one particular part rigoriously.

> (A)Prove that the following collection of subsets defines a topology on the set of naturals $\mathbb{N}$: $\phi , \mathbb{N}$ , $U_n = ${1,2,...,n}, n $\in \mathbb{N}$.

(B)Is $\mathbb{N}$ compact on this topology?

(C)  What are the continuous functions from this space to the space $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers with standard topology?

I have done (A) ,(B) . (It is not compact).

For (C) : Inverse image of open set in $\mathbb{R}$ need to be open in  $\mathbb{N}$.

Open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ is of the form $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} (a_i ,b_i) $ and open sets in $\mathbb{N}$are of the form {$p_1,...,p_r$} so, If f is a continuous function then $f^{-1} (\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} (a_i ,b_i))$={ $p_1,...,p_r$ }but how to define f rigoriously, Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is not constant, simply choose a point $b$ in the image of $f$ that is not equal to $f(1)$. Now choose an open neighbourhood $U$ of $b$ that does not contain $f(1)$. Then $1$ is not contained in $f^{-1}(U)$ and so it is not open.

The constants are trivially continuous.

Comment: Definition: The function $f:X\to Y$ is said to be continuous in $X$ if for any open set $U\in Y$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

By this definition, you need to check what happens to the open neighborhoods of $f(1)$ too!

Comment: @Emo I have shown that I can find an open set $U$, such that $f^{-1}(U)$ is not open. This shows that $f$ is not continuous (unless $f$ is constant).

Comment: I see. You are right!

And for constant functions, let $f(n)=a,\; \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ for a fixed $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Then, for any open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}$ that contains $a$, $f^{-1}(U)=\mathbb{N}$, otherwise, if $U$ doesn't contain $a$, then $f^{-1}(U)=\emptyset$. Hence $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @Emo Yes, exactly what I thought as well!

Comment: @spinosarus123 So, Only constants are continuous. Am I right?